# python Code running time difference

Tags: python, algorithm

I was practicing on Leetcode, I want to ask 3 questions about the codes running time.

1. I noticed that on Leetcode, even the same code will have quite
   different running time if submitted multiple times. And the
   difference is huge, is that normal? I have seen the difference as
   first times beats 26%, but second times beats 51%. That really is
   confusing me, while I am trying to figure out where I am and how
   good the codes are.
2. The actual codes: Leetcode p21, remove element

this is to remove all elements of one value from a list of int, without creating a new list, and return the length of the new list.

```
def removeElement(IntList, val):
    n = 0
    while n < len(IntList): 
        if IntList[n] == val:
           IntList.pop(n)   
        else:
            n += 1  
    return len(IntList)

def removeElement2(IntList, val): 
    while val in IntList:
        IntList.remove(val)
    return len(IntList)
```

You can see that I wrote two functions that will work, and the second one is so much shorter than the first one, but somehow the first one appeared to be faster. And I wonder why.

3. What is the best way to find out if one set of codes is faster than the other one without have to submitted to Leetcode?

Thanks,

Comment: Use [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) to find out how long something takes to run. Right now your question is too broad and isn't really a specific programming question.

Comment: Shorter does not always mean faster.

Comment: @MooingRawr Wow, there is a module in standard library that can do this? Thank you!! It is the 27th in the series, no wonder I have not read to it yet.....

Comment: With the same inputs? Their system is probably running a lot of code for a lot of people. Periods of high load will see individual process performance suffer. This is true of your local machine too, it's just that you usually aren't doing several intensive processes at the same time.

Comment: 1 - yes that's normal. 2 - It is faster because it does less work. 3 - mathematical analysis tells if it will be faster on large data sets. Measurement tells if it is actually faster in the real world on the same data set. You can do measurements with profiling or datetime, if you don't want to run it on leetcode. (But they have good data lined up, with lots of inputs, which is important.)

Comment: @KennyOstrom Thank you, but it is just very difficult to tell which one does less work

Answer (score 0):

For those who is interested, I tried to use timeit to evaluate the two functions. The result is quite interesting, I found that as the list length goes longer, the efficiency of the two functions are changed:

When the list is short, first one is much slower than second one:

```
print(timeit.Timer('removeElement(nums, val)',
                   setup='from __main__ import removeElement; '
                         'nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4];'
                         'val = 4')
      .repeat(3, 1000000))

# >>> [1.8547368030012876, 1.7035995290007122, 1.718884424000862]

print(timeit.Timer('removeElement2(nums, val)',
                   setup='from __main__ import removeElement2; '
                         'nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4];'
                         'val = 4')
      .repeat(3, 1000000))
# >>> [0.4291627630009316, 0.4323928640005761, 0.43043123800089234]
```

However, if I create a extremely long list:

```
print(timeit.Timer('removeElement(nums, val)',
                   setup='from __main__ import removeElement; '
                         'nums = list(range(10)) * 10000;'
                         'val = 4')
      .repeat(3, 100))

# >>> [1.5640779950008437, 1.5756833779996668, 1.6097137039996596]

print(timeit.Timer('removeElement2(nums, val)',
                   setup='from __main__ import removeElement2; '
                         'nums = list(range(10)) * 10000;'
                         'val = 4')
      .repeat(3, 100))
# >>> [11.877236265998363, 11.790503606998755, 12.056773186999635]
```

The second function is much slower now.

Comment: The `val in IntList` will scan the list from the beginning every time through the loop.

Comment: Look up "big O" notation for some insight into this.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Thanks!